# how to understand followed code sample about typedef in c++?

Tags: c++, typedef

```
using namespace boost;

typedef void (*PtrFunc)(any& );
```

how to understand above code sample about typedef in c++?

Comment: It's defining a function pointer.

Comment: It's defining a type named `PtrFunc`: a pointer to a function which accepts a reference to `any` as its argument and returns `void`.

Comment: By reading a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which would explain how pointers to functions are formed. This one in particular makes `PtrFunc` a pointer to function taking `any&` and returning `void`).

Answer (score 1):

This code is declaring a typedef called `PtrFunc` which is a function type which takes a single parameter of type `boost::any&`

You can use it like:

```
void myFunc(any&)
{
    ....
}

PtrFunc pointerToMyFunc = myFunc;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointer to a function returning `void` and accepting `boost:any&` as its sole argument.

It can be used like this:

```
void someFunction(any& arg)
{
    // ...
}

int main() {
    PtrFunc fn = someFunction;
    // ...
    fn(...);

    // You can also do this without a typedef
    void (*other_fn)(any&) = someFunction;
    other_fn(...);

    return 0;
}
```

See this [article](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) for a complete guide to reading type declarations in C (and, consequently, C++).

Also, this [article](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) provides some ASCII art!